# Cannot save the Picture in the given location

Tags: android, camera

I am a beginner in android programming.
Here is a code to take a image and save it in a folder in sdcard. The image is saved in gallery but it is not saved in the location where i want to. Please help...

---

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    }

    public void send(View v)
    {
      Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

      File imagesFolder = new File(
          Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
          "MyImages");

      imagesFolder.mkdirs(); //

      File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");

      Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

      imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

      startActivityForResult(imageIntent,0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, the modified code is:

```
File image = new File("/sdcard/picture.jpg");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage); 

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append a `/` to your MyImages string. eg,

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyImages/");
```

That should create a reference to a directory, not a file as it currently is.

Comment: The directory is created but the picture is still not saved in the location. It is saved only in gallery,